# Using Sharelatex for nomeclature is not working

Tags: nomenclature

Trying to get a list of nomenclature together for my bachelor but it's not working. I have a main file and everything in seperate files(not sure how good of an explanation this is, not very good at LateX). Anyhow the code I'm using works fine when i create a new project, but it refuses to work in my main folder. Could anyone offer some insight/tips?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Comment: you get any error messages?

Comment: No, it just doesn't produce any thing. A blank page

Comment: add `\usepackage[english]{babel}` before the `nomencl` package and try again. the snippet code runs on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/15809583vvjtwfpqhrvj#/60193938/

Comment: Still nothing. It works for me aswell when i start a new project, but it won't comply with my big file

Comment: Does the `.nlg` transcript file have any errors or warnings in it? It may be that the `makeindex` call failed.

Comment: That might be it? How do i find that transcript file?

Comment: Next to the "Recompile" button there's a button with the mouseover label "Logs and output files". Click on that and then on the "Other logs & files" drop down. If the `.nlg` file has been created, then it should show up there.

Comment: It doesn't show, does that mean it's not created? Is there some way to fix that? (And thank you for your help!)

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for you guys
open a file in sharelatex and call it  latexmkrc
then put the following content in it

```
add_cus_dep("nlo", "nls", 0, "nlo2nls");

sub nlo2nls {
        system("makeindex $_[0].nlo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].nls -t $_[0].nlg");
}
```

Then recompile